# framer motion is not working with Nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I'm using Next js 13 with framer motion but it's not working. when i use it inside of `pages` and not using `experimental` flag it works fine. but when i migrate to the `app` and use the `experimental` flag it's not working. it throws an error `React.createContext is not a function`. why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

To fix this you have to add "use client" as the first line in your .jsx file that is using framer motion. You're accessing the client side rendering pipe when you use framer motion; nextJS 13 runs server side rendering by default.

*If you're trying to add exit transitions check out this post for how to do it with the app router (with drawbacks):*

[Exit animation on NextJS 14 Framer Motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77691781/exit-animation-on-nextjs-14-framer-motion/77715364#77715364)