# Exit animation on NextJS 14 Framer Motion

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

I'm attempting to add page transition animations to a Next js 14 app using Framer Motion.
I have PageTransitionLayout.tsx which looks like this

```
'use client';

import { motion, AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import { ReactNode, FC } from "react";

import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

interface ILayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const PageTransitionLayout: FC<ILayoutProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const pathname = usePathname()

  return (
      <AnimatePresence mode={'wait'}>
        <motion.div 
         key={`${pathname}1`}
         className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-screen bg-green-400 origin-middle"
         initial={{ scaleY: 1 }}
         animate={{ scaleY: 0.5 }}
         exit={{ scaleY: 0}}
         transition={{ duration: 1, ease: [0.22, 1, 0.36, 1] }}
       />
       {children}
      </AnimatePresence>
  );
}

export default PageTransitionLayout;
```

and use it in app/contact/pages.tsx like so

```
"use client";

import PageTransitionLayout from "../ui/PageTransitionLayout";

export default function Contact() {
    return (
    <PageTransitionLayout>
      <div className="grid h-[90vh] place-items-center bg-orange-400">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-4xl">Contact</h1>
      </div>
    </PageTransitionLayout>
    )
}
```

but the exit animation of the motion div doesn't fire when navigating to a different page. What may be the issue?

Comment: Can you edit your question to have a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: ok, I've made the edit

Comment: This is currently a shortcoming of the app directory, as it is so fast it doesn't provide the time to the framer library to show an exit transition, to work around this you must wrap your layout.js content in a HOC that will slow it down..Though this breaks using loading.js in your project as it will no longer properly communicate with the Suspense boundaries introduced by using the loading.js file.

Comment: hi @Apezdr, is there any change this happen when framer motion init? I am having trouble when navigating to the page with framer motion. But somehow when I reload the page, it always works. I added and check isClient but won't render anything on first load, this is not recommended in next js I think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to wrap your page in a HOC to slow down the app router in NextJS 13/14. The solution presented below will introduce more issues to work through though such as:

- Suspense Boundaries from using `loading.js` file in app directory will fail to properly load in the children in effect making it so that you can't use `loading.js`

  - The solution will cause the page to re-render more but will effectively provide the exit transitions you're looking for.
- Page will be 'frozen' after it's loaded in, this puts strain on the app router in its current state.

`layout.js`

`/src/app/layout.js` || `/app/layout.js`

```js
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'
import PageAnimatePresence from '@components/HOC/PageAnimatePresence'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Your Website Title',
  description: 'Website metadata description.',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={inter.className + ` bg-blue-500 transition-colors duration-1000`}
        id="page-container"
      >
        <PageAnimatePresence>{children}</PageAnimatePresence>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

`PageAnimatePresence.js`

`/src/app/components/HOC/PageAnimatePresence.js` || `/app/components/HOC/PageAnimatePresence.js`

```js
'use client'

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion'
import FrozenRoute from './FrozenRoute'

const PageAnimatePresence = ({ children }) => {
  const pathname = usePathname()

  return (
    <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
      {/**
       * We use `motion.div` as the first child of `<AnimatePresence />` Component so we can specify page animations at the page level.
       * The `motion.div` Component gets re-evaluated when the `key` prop updates, triggering the animation's lifecycles.
       * During this re-evaluation, the `<FrozenRoute />` Component also gets updated with the new route components.
       */}
      <motion.div key={pathname}>
        <FrozenRoute>{children}</FrozenRoute>
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}

export default PageAnimatePresence
```

`FrozenRoute.js`

`/src/app/components/HOC/FrozenRoute.js` || `/app/components/HOC/FrozenRoute.js`

```js
'use client'

import { useContext, useRef } from 'react'
import { LayoutRouterContext } from 'next/dist/shared/lib/app-router-context.shared-runtime'

const FrozenRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const context = useContext(LayoutRouterContext)
  const frozen = useRef(context).current

  return <LayoutRouterContext.Provider value={frozen}>{children}</LayoutRouterContext.Provider>
}

export default FrozenRoute
```

`template.js`

`/src/app/template.js` || `/app/template.js`

```js
'use client'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

const variants = {
  hidden: { opacity: 0, x: 0, y: 0 },
  enter: { opacity: 1, x: 0, y: 0 },
}

export default function Template({ children }) {
  return (
    <motion.main
      variants={variants}
      initial="hidden"
      exit="hidden"
      animate="enter"
      transition={{ type: 'linear', duration: 0.25 }}
      key="LandingPage"
    >
      {children}
    </motion.main>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. The exit animation is working now.

Comment: Sorry, i can't cast a vote because my reputation is low